# Laravel App on Azure redirects to myweb.scm.azurewebsites.net/route

Tags: php, laravel, azure, nginx

I have a free azure App service that has all the laravel project files inside of wwwroot.

i have updated the APP_URL to https://myweb.azurewebsites.net/ and also in the app.php just to be on the safe side.

The App is able to load the welcome page on https://myweb.azurewebsites.net/ but once i go to /home it redirects to https://myweb.scm.azurewebsites.net/home. I need assistance on why its redirecting to https://myweb.scm.azurewebsites.net/home and not https://myweb.azurewebsites.net/home?

Im thinking its something to do with my default config below. I am very new to nginx.

Below is my default for nginx

```
server {
#proxy_cache cache;
    #proxy_cache_valid 200 1s;
listen 8080;
listen [::]:8080;
root /home/site/wwwroot/public;
index  index.php index.html index.htm;
server_name  myweb.azurewebsites.net www.myweb.azurewebsites.net;
port_in_redirect off;



location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}



# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /html/;
}
    
    
    
# Disable .git directory
location ~ /\.git {
    deny all;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;

# Add locations of phpmyadmin here.
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout         300;
    fastcgi_send_timeout           3600;
    fastcgi_read_timeout           3600;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
}
```

}